# Probability tree diagrams

Tags: probability, trees

> **Exercice** : True or false
>
> Let $E$ and $F$ be two events of an experiment.

$$\mathbb{P}(E| \bar{F})=1-\mathbb{P}(E| F)$$

Solution :

Flase due to the Law of total probability we've:

$$\mathbb{P}(E| \bar{F}) +\mathbb{P}(E| F)=\mathbb{P}(E)$$ which is not necessarily equal $1$

Could anyone explain me this by using **Probability tree diagrams** they can helps me to understand that very well.

Comment: Although the statement is false, I find the "Law of total probability" cited above is also false.  Perhaps you have misquoted that "law"?

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

The Law of Total Probability is: $$\Bbb P(\bar F\mid E)+\Bbb P(F\mid E)= 1$$

And by Bayes' Rule:
$$\frac{\Bbb P(E\mid\bar F)\Bbb P(\bar F)}{\Bbb P(E)}+\frac{\Bbb P(E\mid F)\Bbb P(F)}{\Bbb P(E)} = 1$$

So:$$\Bbb P(E\mid\bar F)\Bbb P(\bar F)+\Bbb P(E\mid F)\Bbb P(F) = \Bbb P(E)$$

But this still does not really disprove the *original* claim, does it?

---

**Hint:** Try a disproof by counter example.   Can you find two events $E,F$ such that $\,\Bbb P(E\mid\bar F)+\Bbb P(E\mid F)\neq 1\,$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the experiment being the roll of f single die, and let the events be:
$F$ - the result is even.
$E$ - the result is 6.
Now, clearly $P(E)=\frac{1}{6}$, $P(E|F)=\frac{1}{3}$ and $P(E|\bar{F})=0$.

Two things can be observed now, first of all that indeed $P(E|\bar{F})+P(E|F)\neq 1$ as required, but also that $P(E|\bar{F})+P(E|F)\neq P(E)$ contrary to your claim.

You can easily draw the probability tree for that example

Answer (score 0):

Take $E = \Omega$. Then $P(E|F) + P(E|\overline F) = 2$.

Comment: @Educ, no. Just the definition.

Comment: but can used it can't we ? $$A \subset  B \implies Pr(B \mid A)=Pr(B)$$

Comment: @ No. $Pr(B \mid A)=1$.

Comment: note that $F \subset  E$ then $E\cap F=F $ so $P(E\cap F)=P(F)$
 $$P(E|F) + P(E|\overline F) =\dfrac{P(E\cap F)}{P(F)} + \dfrac{P(E \cap \overline F)}{P(\overline F)}=\dfrac{P( F)}{P(F)} + \dfrac{P( \overline F)}{P(\overline F)}=1+1=2 $$